# I created an app using PHP/MySQL as back end. BASE URL is not working

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have created Android app using PHP/MySQL as back end. The code is working in Emulator if its local host but its not working if I point the URL to a site.

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/testcode/";--->Working
public static final String BASE_URL ="https://www.abc.ccc/php/";--->Not Working
```

**Error**

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: HTTP 500
```

The App should work in the host like local one. Please share your thought on this one.

Comment: HTTP 500 is internal server error some how server is not able to handle your request

Comment: This is working fine if I point to local IP

Comment: Http 500 means internal server error. Which means your request could not be successful proceeded. Maybe configuration problem on server side, check for error log

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help. It due to PHP issue and I fixed it and its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to PHP code issue and Android is not able to handle so, I fixed the code in the back end and its working now. Thanks everyone for your help.